# MongoDB group aggregate with nested array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a collection with the following structure (i'll post a link to playground because it's quite big):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/WNga0mze0WS

Just a brief explanation, we are looking for `materias` (subjects) and `assuntos` (topics) and we want that aggregate to return an array of `nomes` (name of that topic) that have 3 times or more `erros` (errors) than `acertos` (correct), so that we could display what topics the student needs to get better at. The other results does not matter, only if it is 3 times or more.

I wanted to make an aggregate that would group the `user.uid`, because on this collection you could have the results from another user, and try to add all erros and correct answers based on the topic name (`assuntos.nome`).

I have tried quite a few things so far, but this is the last thing I've tried:

```
db.aggregate([
          { $unwind: "$materias" },
          { $unwind: "$materias.assuntos" },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: {
                _id: "$user.uid",
                nome: "$materias.assuntos.nome",
                total: "$materias.assuntos.total",
                acertos: "$materias.assuntos.acertos",
                erros: "$materias.assuntos.erros",
                // sumErro: {
                //   $sum: {
                //     "$toInt": "$materias.assuntos.erros"
                //   }
                // },
                teste: {
                  // $sum: {
                  "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                      "$and": [
                        {
                          "$gte": [
                            "$materias.assuntos.erros", 3
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "$gte": [
                            "$materias.assuntos.erros",
                            { $multiply: [ "$materias.assuntos.acertos", 3 ] }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "then": "$materias.assuntos.erros",
                    "else": "$$REMOVE",
                  }
                  // }
                }
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: {
                _id: "$_id._id",
                nome: "$_id.nome",
                erros: "$_id.erros",
                teste: "$_id.teste"
              },
            }
          }
        ])
```

I also tried grouping just by the uid and materias.assuntos.nome and then later grouping to get the results but couldn't make it. The condition I did there was for what I was looking for that is the erros beeing 3x more than acertos, and i figured erros also needed to be 3 or more.

I was expecting one result to have at least more than 3 erros but I'm doing something wrong because it is not adding those values according to the name of the topic.

I can also provide another document if needed because the one I sent only have 1 topic that has 3x more erros than acertos.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution this way by working on the playground

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$materias"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$materias.assuntos"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        user: "$user.uid",
        nomeAssunto: "$materias.assuntos.nome"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$materias.assuntos.total"
      },
      acertos: {
        $sum: "$materias.assuntos.acertos"
      },
      erros: {
        $sum: "$materias.assuntos.erros"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.user",
      assuntos: {
        $push: {
          nome: "$_id.nomeAssunto",
          total: "$total",
          acertos: "$acertos",
          erros: "$erros"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      user: "$_id",
      assuntos: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$assuntos",
          as: "assunto",
          cond: {
            "$and": [
              {
                $gte: [
                  "$$assunto.erros",
                  3
                ]
              },
              {
                $lte: [
                  {
                    $multiply: [
                      "$$assunto.acertos",
                      3
                    ]
                  },
                  "$$assunto.erros"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      assuntos: {
        "$exists": true,
        "$not": {
          "$size": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```